# why is requirejs on node not loading the require specified before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

Update...

Even without the async load file operation, it still doesn't run how I would expect it to based on your explanation...for example

part0_start.js...

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire : require
});
requirejs([ 'part1_setup'], function( part1_setup ) {//this callback executes when part1_setup has been compiled and run
    console.log( 'part1_setup callback called')
})
```

part1_setup.js...

```
requirejs( [ 'stopwatchObject' ], function( stopwatch ) {//run the callback function when stopwatchObject is loaded...
    console.log( 'stopwatch object compiled' );
})
```

stopwatchObject.js...

```
define ( [], function() {//this anonymous function happens straight away, go straight to the callback function on line below...
    console.log( "stopwatch object");
})
```

I would expect this to output

```
stopwatch object
stopwatch object compiled
part1_setup callback called
```

but it actually outputs...

```
part1_setup callback called
stopwatch object
stopwatch object compiled
```

Or am I overlooking something obvious?  Thanks again for your feedback.

---

My understanding of requirejs is that it allows me to specify module(s) to be loaded before continuing the thread, allowing me to be block if I want.  It has worked this way when I've previously used it.  However when I use it with node, this aspect of it no longer works.  Obviously I know node is non-blocking, is this the reason why require isn't functioning like I expect it to.
For example...

test.txt

```
test text test text test text test text test text test text test text
```

start.js

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire : require
});
requirejs([ 'part1'], function( part1 ) {
    console.log( 'loaded' )
})
```

part1.js

```
define([], function() {
var fs = require('fs'), filename = 'test.txt';
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    this.text = data;
    console.log( this.text );
})
```

})

outputs in the following order...

```
module loaded
test text test text test text test text test text test text test text
```

But if I was specifying require part1.js, should it not compile this completely and log the loaded text before getting to logging 'loaded'?

Comment: I've just noticed you edited your question. If you change your `requirejs` call with a `define` call in your `part1_setup` you should get the order you expect. If somehow there's still an issue, I would suggest asking a new question, because the problem in your edit is *related* but *conceptually different* from your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is exactly what is expected. Here is the sequence of events:

1. `requirejs([ 'part1'],` tells RequireJS to initiate the loading of `part1`. The loading will complete some time in the future.
2. RequireJS fetches the code of `part1` and executes it. It finds an anonymous `define` which RequireJS interprets as being the definition of `part1` so it executes the callback passed to the `define`.
3. The line `fs.readFile` is executed. This initiates the reading the file. The operation will complete some time in the future. **This is asynchronous.**
4. The execution of the callback passed to `define` continues and completes. If you had a `console.log` statement after `fs.readFile`, you'd see its output right there *before* the contents of the file.
5. Since execution of the callback passed to `define` is done, RequireJS then can call the callback that was passed to `requirejs([ 'part1'],`. **There is no reason this must be delayed.** In particular, the `fs.readFile` operation has no bearing on this.
6. The file is eventually read and the callback passed to `fs.readFile` is called.

If you used `fs.readFileSync` then you'd get the behavior you are expecting.

Side note: using `this.text` in your code is probably not doing what you think it is doing. At that point in your code `this === global`.